# Grabing data from a column that has more then one value, with php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Basically I have products data stored in a database which also have a field called "tags" which is designed to store tags about that specific product. These tags are stored in a format like so:

"tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4"

The question is say that I want to have a page where a user can view all the latest products for that specific tag. How can I possibly accomplish this without taking every single product, fetching the "tag" field, separating them and then finally checking if that specific tag exists in there?

Is it possible to do this with a mysql command?

I am sorry I didnt post any code, I just am not sure how I should go about doing something like this in general.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most efficient way, but:

```
WHERE tags LIKE '%$search_tag%'
```

This assumes that a tag that is searched for cannot be contained by another tag, or you'd need:

```
WHERE
   tags LIKE '%,$search_tag%'
   OR tags LIKE '%$search_tag,%'
   OR tags = '$search_tag'
```

Obviously, `search_tag` needs to be escaped properly.

Comment: Hmm, thank you. Can you possibly recommend a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Yes LIKE is the best way to do this, for more functional and big websites you better create a new table saving tags and using products id as foreign key

Comment: @user1701398 as Aman says, it would be more efficient to restructure your database to make the tags individual indices.

Answer (score 1):

You should [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your database, so you can perform the search straight via SQL query.